# How can I create a button to clear all data from a table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite, button

I want to create a button that will clear all the data in my table.  I am using Rails 4 and SQLLite3.

I populated a table using Faker with 100 people (first_name, last_name, age).  The data is presented in a view.  On the same view page, I want to have a button that will delete all the data in the table (but not the table itself, i.e. not drop the table).

*Bonus points if it dynamically updates the page; although, I know that might add a lot to the code.

Let me know if I need to post anything.  I am pretty new to Rails, so please feel free to explain in as much detail as possible.  Thank you!

As an alternative, instead of the button, just provide the method for clearing the data from the table.  Thanks.

This is all the code, including the method (provided below) that I was looking for to delete the data.

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
def loaddata
    for i in 0..100
        first_name = Faker::Name.first_name
        last_name = Faker::Name.last_name
        age = Faker::Number.number(2)

        p = Person.new(first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name, age: age)

        p.save
    end

    head :ok
end

def index
    @people = Person.all
end

def delete
    @people = Person.delete_all()
    head :ok
end

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [delete_all ActiveRecord method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/delete_all/class).
Just use without parameters and it will delete all your records

```
Model.delete_all
```